# What alternatives to Eternl mobile wallet with dApp connectors do exist for Cardano?

Tags: wallet, decentralized-applications, lightwallet, mobile-wallet

I'm currently using Eternl on my mobile phone to connect to and use dApps. However, they only allow a select few dApps to be used within the wallet and on top of that charge a fee for using dApps like Minswap.

Are there any other Cardano mobile-wallets that support dApps, preferably without restrictions, so I can connect to any website I want? And if not, are there any other mobile-wallets that support dApp connection?

Answer (score 1):

The mobile version of Flint Wallet [is said to support arbitrary CIP30 dapps](https://medium.com/dcspark/flint-wallets-innovative-mobile-dapp-browser-c77d68f5b10b). For example, I've successfully run Marlowe transactions on Mobile using Flint.